# pass a list of maps to Terraform from Azure DevOps variable group

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-application-gateway

When i want to pass a list of map to a Terraform variable(where i use dynamic block to iterate over this list) i get this error:

**│ Cannot use a string value in for_each. An iterable collection is required.**

My list of maps in my variable group in Azure Devops:

```
{ "host" = "mysite1.com", "name" = "healthprobe1", "path" = "/healthcheck1" },
{ "host" = "mysite2.com", "name" = "healthprobe2", "path" = "/healthcheck2" },
{ "host" = "mysite2.com", "name" = "healthprobe3", "path" = "/healthcheck3" }
```

My variable in variable group:

[image]
My Terraform configuration which iterate over a list of maps:

```
The variable:
variable "PROBES" {
  default     = [{}]
}
```

The dynamic block:

```
  dynamic "probe" {
    for_each = var.PROBES

    content {
      host                                      = probe.value.host
      interval                                  = 30
      minimum_servers                           = 0
      name                                      = probe.value.name
      path                                      = probe.value.path
      pick_host_name_from_backend_http_settings = false
      protocol                                  = local.protocol
      timeout                                   = 30
      unhealthy_threshold                       = 3
      match {
        status_code = ["200-399"]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you check what `PROBES` is, buy creating an `output` with a value of `var.PROBES`?

Comment: var.PROBES is "{ \"host\" = \"mysite1.com\", \"name\" = \"healthprobe1\", \"path\" = \"/healthcheck\"  }"

Answer (score 1):

One of the options (but needs to be tested) is to define the `PROBES` variable as string and into your `dynamic` block change from

```
dynamic "probe" {
    for_each = var.PROBES
...
}
```

to

```
dynamic "probe" {
    for_each = tomap(jsondecode(var.PROBES))
...
}
```

to explicitly convert your string input variable to a structured object

Reference:

- [tomap](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/tomap)
- [jsondecode](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/jsondecode)

**EDIT** Incorrectly referencing at first at `jsonencode` function while this should refer to **`jsondecode`** functionality

Comment: Thanks you that worked using jsondecode function and adding brackets [] to the variable:[{ "host" = "mysite1.com", "name" = "healthprobe1", "path" = "/healthcheck1" },
{ "host" = "mysite2.com", "name" = "healthprobe2", "path" = "/healthcheck2" },
{ "host" = "mysite2.com", "name" = "healthprobe3", "path" = "/healthcheck3" }]